# PHP - Open CSV, do some math and make another CSV

Tags: php, csv

**Problem**
I'm a newbie, so this may be easy, but I'm stuck.
I've got a CSV file, with a row looking like that:

kamis;4;0,45;0,69;
User is able to upload the file and apply some math on it. Then he is able to download file with the math applied.
I've converted CSV into Array

```
[0]=> array(5) { ["nazwa"]=> string(5) "kamis" ["iloć"]=> string(1) "4" ["koszt"]=> string(4) "0,45" ["cena"]=> string(4) "0,69" [""]=> string(0) "" }
```

Now I'd like to convert all "columns" into arrays and apply math on them, then I'd like to put them into a new CSV file.
**Question**
How to put CSV columns into separate arrays and after calculations put them later on into a new CSV file ?

Comment: [Try the php Documentation](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: If your csv file has acceptable format, then you can use fgetcsv 
[fgetcsv]

after you do operations with your file, you can store that array back into csv with this
[fputcsv]


  [1]: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php
  [2]: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: You're going to have to write a program.  Ideally, you'll use the CSV functions that are built in to PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function I use, you just pass it a filename and an associative array of data (like your example) and it will use whatever key values are in the first row for column headings and then output the values of all rows. If nothing else you should be able to learn from this:

```
public function outputCsv($fileName, $assocDataArray)
{
    ob_clean();
    header( 'Content-Type: text/csv' );
    header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$fileName);
    if(isset($assocDataArray['0'])){
        $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        fputcsv($fp, array_keys($assocDataArray['0']));
        foreach($assocDataArray AS $values){
            fputcsv($fp, $values);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
    ob_flush();
}
```

Comment: I have not made it work yet, but it seems like a good solution. I'll let you know when it's done. Thanks !

Comment: it's just the latter part for outputting the csv. The read functions are similar. In this case i'm just writing to the php request, but you could easily modify that fopen to write to a location on disk.

Comment: I've just made it work - works perfectly as expected.